# MongoDB multiple condition on subset

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a DB like this:

```
Job
  ID
  Name
  LeaderID
  Workers
    ID
    Enabled
Person
  ID
  Name
```

To retrieve all jobs which a person with id `id` is either Leader or one of Workers, I have a working query:

```
find([{
  $match: {
    $or:[{"LeaderID": id}, {"Workers.ID": id}]
  },
  ...
]);
```

So how can I modify this so that it only matches Workers with `"Enabled": true`.
I thought of `$or:[{"LeaderID": id}, {$and: [{"Workers.ID": id}, {"Workers.Enabled": true}]}]` but I'm sure it won't work.

Comment: Your query should work. `$or:[{"LeaderID": id}, {$and: [{"Workers.ID": id}, {"Workers.Enabled": true}]}]`

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) operator to filter workers with enabled as true.
For example, you could do:

```
db.collection.find( {
$or: [
      {"LeaderID": 2}, 
      {"Workers": { $elemMatch : {"ID": 2, "Enabled" :false} } }
     ]

})
```